# How can I get radio button behaviour with images?

Tags: html

I want to add an image to a radio button so that when one button is selected all other button should be in non-selected mode (like a radio button group behaves).

But I want to achieve it with images. What is the way to do it?

Comment: Some good answers here, but no accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you don‘t mind the radio buttons being visible (which is probably a good idea, so that users understand what’s going on more easily), this should do:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Images</legend>

    <label for="image_1">
        <input id="image_1" name="image" type="radio">

        <img>
    </label>

    <label for="image_2">
        <input id="image_2" name="image" type="radio">

        <img>
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Otherwise, if you really just want your images to behave like radio buttons, then you’ll need to write some JavaScript that makes the images imitate all the behaviour of radio buttons (i.e. assign functions to the `onclick` event of the images, and other events so that they work with keyboards for users who don’t use mice).

You could still include the radio buttons, but hide them via CSS, and write your JavaScript so that it changes the state of the hidden radio buttons when users interact with the images.

Comment: But it shows radio button & Image both.I want instead of button only images should be displayed & it should behave like radio group.On selection on one button other buttons should be deselected.

Comment: @Eshika: yeah, I did say “If you don’t mind the radio buttons being visible“, and explained why that might be a good idea. If you really want just the images to behave like radio buttons, then you’ll need to write some JavaScript that copies all the behaviour of radio buttons, and applies it to your images (i.e. use the `onclick` event of the images to record that an image is selected, that all other images are unselected, and to update the CSS of the image to somehow reflect that). We’re not here to write that code for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" />
```

And other group of radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="4" />
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support older browsers (IE) I think you'll have to do it with js. Consider this html:

```
<img class="radio" src="radio1.jpg" id="radio1"/>
<img class="radio" src="radio2.jpg" id="radio2"/>
<img class="radio" src="radio3.jpg" id="radio3"/>
<img class="radio" src="radio4.jpg" id="radio4"/>
<img class="radio" src="radio5.jpg" id="radio5"/>
```

and jquery:

```
$(".radio").click(function(){
    $("this").addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected")
})
```

to read selected value just get the id of `img.selected`.

Comment: Just make sure the state (selected or not) is visually distinguishable.